# How to Binding StackLayout data in code behind Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have

1. Page.xml

   ```
   <ListView x:Name="myCart" HasUnevenRows="true">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
             <Grid Padding="0" Margin="0">
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                 <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
               </Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                 <Label TextColor="#333" Text="111" />
               </Grid>
             </Grid>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>

   <StackLayout x:Name="stdata">
     <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <Label TextColor="#333" Text="111" />
       </DataTemplate>
     </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
   </StackLayout>
   ```
2. Page.xml.cs

   ```
   ....
   var mycartss = Preferences.Get("CartUser", "defaultcart");
   var getcartss = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CartUser>>(mycartss);
   cartUsers = getcartss;
   // myCart.ItemsSource = cartUsers; -->If I use ListView I can Binding data like this
   stdata.BindableLayout.ItemsSource.....????
   ```

**Problem 1:** I have set the property HasUnevenRows="true" but it still doesn't work

[image]

**Problem 2:** If I use StackLayout then how do I bind data in code behind? `stdata.BindableLayout.ItemsSource.....????`

I have consulted some articles on stackoverflow.com but it is quite cumbersome for me. Hope for help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is covered in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts#populate-a-bindable-layout-with-data)

```
BindableLayout.SetItemsSource(stdata, cartUsers);
```

Comment: Thank sir very much